# Avoid system message box in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to know if there is a way to avoid system message pop up box and display customized message box instead.

for example: if a user clicks on a button to launch an app and if that app is not installed in phone, user will see a system message box "to search for an app in play store".Instead I want to display customized message box.

Comment: You can add custom popup messages **in app**.. are you trying to have a customized message box within your application or at system level ? (At system level this is not possible..)

Comment: What you're looking for is a contentDialog